# How to calculate the expectation of the square of the number of heads in N tosses?

Tags: probability, expectation, binomial-distribution

Suppose we have a coin that has a probability $p$ of landing head. Let H be the number of heads obtained in N tosses. How to calculate $E(H^2)$? I need this to calculate some other things. But I can't figure out. I know I need to take $\sum x^2p(x)$, but I am unable to evaluate it to a nice expression.

Comment: I assume the tosses are independent, is that right? Is the coin fair?

Comment: @bof the coin has probability of p of landing head

Comment: So you now have three answers using three different approaches, any one of which may or may not be useful to you depending on what "other things" you need this for and exactly why you had trouble getting a "nice expression." If one of the answers gave you the insight you needed, now would be a good time to accept it; if not, you might consider editing the question again to give more detail about what you need and what you were able to find yourself before you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E_n[H^2] = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}k^2 =n^2p^2 - np^2 + np $$

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're talking about $N$ **independent** coin tosses. (Actually, the calculation below assumes only that the tosses are **pairwise** independent.) Let $p$ be the probability that the coin comes up heads, and let $q=1-p$ be the probability that it comes up tails.

Let $H_i$ be the indicator variable which takes the value $1$ if the $i^{\text{th}}$ toss comes up heads, $0$ otherwise. Thus
$$H=H_1+H_2+\cdots+H_N.$$
and
$$H^2=(H_1+\cdots+H_N)^2=\sum_{i=1}^NH_i^2+\sum_{i\ne j}H_iH_j,$$
so
$$E(H^2)=\sum_{i=1}^NE(H_i^2)+\sum_{i\ne j}E(H_iH_j)=\sum_{i=1}^Np+\sum_{i\ne j}p^2$$$$=Np+N(N-1)p^2=Np(1-p)+N^2p^2=Npq+E(H)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you know $H$ follows a binomial distribution with parameters $N, p$. Since the variance and the expectation of the binomial distribution are well-known, you can solve the variance formula for $E[H^2]$ and do
$$E[H^2] = \operatorname{Var}(H)+(E[X])^2 = Np(1-p) +(Np)^2.$$

Of course, if you are proving what the variance value is ("calculate some other things"), this doesn't quite work.